# Where to set The receiving account for in App purchase android?

Tags: android, in-app-billing

I am developing an android application, right now I have implemented the in app purchase in  functionality in a test code, I studied the documentation but did not find When the user selects an item to purchase where the payment will be received,
my question is where I have to give the account number for receiving the payment. 
Any help, link or tutorial will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

you will have to create merchant account or your existing publisher account will also work...
go to [this](https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?service=sierra&continue=https://checkout.google.com/main?upgrade=true&hl=en_GB&nui=1&ltmpl=default&sacu=1) link to configure your merchant account and give your bank details over there...

and you can find our In-App Billing Policies [here...](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1153481)

just to let you know that Google doesn't allow indian publisher to sell digital contents